# print hexadecimal with capital letters

Tags: c, unicode, hex, printf, widechar

I'm trying to print the Unicode value of a wide character like so:

```
wchar_t w = '\u00A1';   // U+00A1 Inverted Exclamation Mark ¡
wprintf("U+%.4x",w);    // prints U+00a1
```

I'd like the output to be `U+00A1` instead of `U+00a1`. Is there a `printf` specifier to do this or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: Use capital `X` instead of lower case `x`.

Comment: Experiment with `"%x"` and `"%X"`...

Comment: Use uppercase %X

Comment: ...note `%x` and `%X` expect the argument to be `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess that was pretty simple, use `%X` instead of `%x`.

```
wchar_t w = '\u00A1';   // U+00A1 Inverted Exclamation Mark ¡
wprintf("U+%.4x",w);    // prints U+00A1
```

Thanks, [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054197/print-hexadecimal-with-capital-letters#comment75133277_44054197) and [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054197/print-hexadecimal-with-capital-letters#comment75133285_44054197) and [Felix Palmen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054197/print-hexadecimal-with-capital-letters#comment75133291_44054197).